# How do I list a systemd unit's wants?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I know that I can see a unit's dependencies with `systemctl list-dependencies unit`, but is it possible to see a tree of reverse-dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `--reverse` will do this.

```
systemctl list-dependencies --reverse unit
```

From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--reverse):

> Show reverse dependencies between units with list-dependencies, i.e.
>   follow dependencies of type WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, PartOf=, BoundBy=,
>   instead of Wants= and similar.